# Integrating Google Talk and Hangout in Android App

Tags: android, api, google-talk, google-hangouts

```
I have multiple questions :
```

1. Google announced that Hangout is replacing Gtalk from May 2013. So on their android devices some people have updated from Gtalk to Hangout while some are still using Gtalk. So if I have to use an API to transfer exchange data from my android app to Google Chat Messenger , how and what should I use to make it compatible for both.
2. What library should I use to integrate Gtalk/Hangout with my android app ? And where would I get something like SDK Reference Docs for Gtalk/Hangout ?
3. Can I get any sample implementation of the same anywhere(possibly GitHub) ?

Comment: I am not aware of an Android SDK for either Gtalk or Hangout.

Comment: Then how people are integrating Gtalk/Hangout in their android apps , or how they are able to exchange data from Gtalk/Hangout with their android apps ?

Comment: I am not aware of anyone doing anything like that, other than perhaps via `ACTION_SEND` to initiate some sort of conversation, if either of those apps supports `ACTION_SEND`. Google Talk was XMPP-based, and so some apps might be interoperating with it that way, though XMPP support is (was?) deprecated by Google.

Comment: So how am I supposed to do this ? :(